How to demodulate an AM signal in MATLAB?
I'm trying to demodulate a given AM signal in MATLAB, but the results are not satisfactory as you can see:
result
How can I obtain the demodulated signal (red) correctly?
The signal that is modulated and demodulated is
xc = Ac * (1 + m * exp(-(t/T0).^2)) .* cos(2 * pi * fc * t);

Thanks in advance.
Code implemented:
Base code:
% Parámetros de la señal
Ac = 5;           % Amplitud de la portadora
m = 0.2;          % Índice de modulación
T0 = 2e-6;        % Tiempo constante (2 microsegundos)
fc = 30e6;        % Frecuencia de la portadora (30 MHz)
bw = 15e6;        % Ancho de banda del demodulador (15 MHz)
fs= 100e6;

% Tiempo
t = linspace(-5e-6, 5e-6, 1e6);  % 1 millón de muestras entre -5 y 5 microsegundos

% Señal modulada en AM
xc = Ac * (1 + m * exp(-(t/T0).^2)) .* cos(2 * pi * fc * t);

%Señal demodulada
xd= demod_AM(xc,fc,fs,bw,t);

%teórica
env_teorica = Ac * (1 + m * exp(-(t/T).^2));

plot(t,xd,t,env_teorica)

Function implemented for demodulating the AM signal:
function xd=demod_AM(xc,fc,fs,bw,t)
 % xd = señal demodulada: x_d(t)
 % xc = señal modulada: x_c(t)
 % fc = frecuencia de la portadora
 % fs = frecuencia de muestreo
 % bw = ancho de banda del filtro
 % t = vector de tiempos

% Mezclar la señal modulada con la portadora (detección coherente)
mixed_signal = xc .* cos(2 * pi * fc * t);

xd= lowpass(mixed_signal,fs,bw,5);

end

Lowpass band filter:
function newdata = lowpass(data,samprate,cutoff,order)

% newdata = lowpass(data,samprate,cutoff,order)
%
% performs a lowpass filtering of the input data
% using an nth order zero phase lag butterworth filter
%
% given -> data (data)
%   -> samprate (Hz)
%   -> cutoff freq (Hz)
%   -> order of filter (optional: default 2nd order)
%
% returns -> filtered data

if nargin==3 order=2; end; % default to 2nd order

% get filter paramters A and B
[B,A] = butter(order,cutoff/(samprate/2));
% perform filtering
newdata = filtfilt(B,A,data);

